# ReferenceError: electron is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-error, referenceerror

I am getting the following error in the given SSCCE code:

```
Error: ReferenceError: electron is not defined
Source File: http://localhost/testingOne.php
Line: 1
```

While `'electron'` is a string. So why am I getting this error. WHile I tried the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618228/referenceerrorsomething-anything-nothing-is-not-defined) and wrapped `electron` and `proton` in `"` but that gives:

```
Error: SyntaxError: syntax error
Source File: http://localhost/testingOne.php
Line: 1, Column: 12
Source Code:
clickButton(
```

**Code:**

```
<?php 

echo '<html><head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <script>
        function clickButton(alp, bet) {
            alert(alp);
            alert(bet);
        }
    </script>
</head><body>';

$array = array('alpha'=>'electron', 'beta'=>'proton');

echo '<button type="button" onclick="clickButton('. $array['alpha'].','.$array['beta'] .')" >Click Me</button>';

echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to View Source on the actual HTML being created, you'd see:

```
<button type="button" onclick="clickButton(electron,proton)" >Click Me</button>
```

You need to add quotes *around* the output values to turn them into Javascript string literals:

```
echo '<button type="button" onclick="clickButton(\''. $array['alpha'].'\',\''.$array['beta'] .'\')" >Click Me</button>';
```

to give:

```
<button type="button" onclick="clickButton('electron','proton')" >Click Me</button>
```